# Can't start deluge

Tags: windows

i'm using windowsXp, sp3 ,setup deluge-1.2.0_rc3-win32-setup.exe, but when i try \deluge\deluge-python\deluge.exe , an error happen
[error] **init**:1982 Dll load failed: The specified module could not be found.
...
...
..
ImportError: Dll load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[error] xxxxxx ui:147 There was an error whilst launching the request UI: gtk
[error] xxxxxx ui:148 Look at the traceback above for more information

so, deluge don't start :(

Answer (score 0):

i had no prob in installing. I gave complete install. Didn't give recommended. And make sure you select proper directory for installing dll files. (in my case it was the recommended /bin option). try reinstalling.